# Travels using graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Someone can help me to think in the better way to adapt Dijkstra's Algorithm in these conditions? All I thought didn't was good.

Example of input:

GP4578 MADRID 01:00 PORTO 02:00

IK6587 PORTO 03:00 VALENCIA 05:00 05:30 TENERIFE 08:00

AB5874 VALENCIA 05:40 BERLIM 10:00

"VALENCIA 05:00 05:30" This is a stopover, all of them are about 30min.
The flight has arrival and departure time, flight number, the origin and detination city.

So, I need get the shortest path from a city to another, ok, no problem.
I can't to structure this, I've been tried since the last week.
Someone can give me ideias? Who are my vertex? How to use the edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the graph I propose:
Two kinds of vertices:

1. departure vertex: airport+departure time
2. arrival vertex: airport + arrival time.

Two kind of edges:

1. flight edge: from a departure vertex to an arrival vertex
2. wait edge: from an arrival vertex to a departure vertex of later time in the same airport.

The weights on the edges are duration, the problem is single-source-shortest-path, and you can solve it using Dijstra's algorithm as you mention.
As for the flights with intermediate landing, just split them into sections.

Comment: Isn't clear to me how I can "connect" the vertex with the edges. What is inside Flight Edge object? The weight and the memory address of the departure and arrival vertex? Anyway, I'm very grateful by your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. How to represent a directed graph in C++? There are many possibilities. For example, a graph can be a std::vector of Vertex, where a vertex holds  airport, time, departure/arrival, and a vector of outgoing edges. An Edge contains the weight and the index of the destination vertex. BTW, grateful users in SO tend to vote for the answers they're grateful for.